# Highcharts/Highmaps in ionic - map is not showing

Tags: highcharts

1. Add Plugin 'angular2-highcharts'
2. add code in ionViewDidLoad()

   ```
    var chart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
         chart: {
           map: 'custom/europe',
           spacingBottom: 20
         },

       title: {
          text: 'Europe time zones'
        },

       legend: {
          enabled: true
       },

       plotOptions: {
         map: {
           allAreas: false,
           dataLabels: {
             enabled: true,
             color: '#FFFFFF',
             style: {
             fontWeight: 'bold'
             },
         // Only show dataLabels for areas with high label rank
          format: null,
          formatter: function () {
           if (this.point.properties && this.point.properties.labelrank.toString() < 5) {
               return this.point.properties['iso-a2'];
           }
       }
           },
           tooltip: {
             headerFormat: '',
             pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{series.name}</b>'
         }
         }
       },


       })
   ```

Comment: Any tutorial you are following? Can you please share the link? Also just wanted to know, whether it was working previously?

Comment: Where do you load map data? Please describe what you have more precisely and add an example or online demo. Have you considered using official Highcharts wrapper `highcharts-angular`. It can be downloaded here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: @anuragal I am using "https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo".. map was never working

Comment: I am facing the same issue, the map is not showing, did you figure out how to solve this issue?